# I am unable to print anything in jtextarea in netbeans generated gui

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, addressbook

**First Class** I just want to print in the text area.

```
package newaddressbook;

import com.sun.accessibility.internal.resources.accessibility;

public class PersonInfo {

    String name, address, phone_Number;

    public PersonInfo() {

    }

    public PersonInfo(String name, String address, String phone_Number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone_Number = phone_Number;
    }

    public void print(){
        AddressBook_GUI access = new AddressBook_GUI();
        access.textarea.setText(name + address + phone_Number);
    }
}
```

**GUI Class**

```
package newaddressbook;

public class AddressBook_GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form AddressBook_GUI
     */
    public AddressBook_GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        textarea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        textarea.setColumns(20);
        textarea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(textarea);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 278, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddressBook_GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddressBook_GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddressBook_GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddressBook_GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AddressBook_GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
            });

        PersonInfo obj = new PersonInfo("Faizan", "P-148", "03227690050");
        obj.print();
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    public javax.swing.JTextArea textarea;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You're creating two instances of `AddressBook_GUI` - one is visible (the one you're not updating) and one is not (the one you are updating)

Comment: See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.